# Why falling ants will get less damage than a human?

Tags: energy, collision

I know this is related to the mass of the object, so that an ant falling will have a little terminal velocity and won't get much damage, when compared to a human which will reach an higher velocity.
I'm trying to explain this to myself: the energy that is "converted to damage" is the final kinetic energy $\frac{1}{2}mv_f^2$, so that a human will inevitably result in more damage, because she would reach a higher velocity. But I'm wondering how the mass intervenes in this:

1. It intervenes indirectly in the fact that having more mass (well, with respect to the section area of course) leads to a weaker air resistance and, thus, to a higher velocity
2. It also intervenes "directly" because kinetic energy is higher for an higher mass, i.e. a stronger force is needed to stop a more massive object (please, correct me, if I'm not saying things right)

So, the **big question**: if an ant fell with the same velocity as a human being, would it still experience less damage on impact because it has less mass?

I know this question may not be that simple as also anatomy of an ant should be taken into account, but I'm trying to exemplify things to understand what happens. Thanks to whoever will help!

Comment: Think of kinetic energy of an ant when it hits the ground. Then compare that how much energy it takes to damage an ant, say by finding out how much mass an ant can carry without causing damage to its limbs. Then compare the two.

Comment: Does this article answer your question? https://beta.theglobeandmail.com/technology/ants-slow-fall-key-to-survival/article4275684/?ref=https://www.theglobeandmail.com&

Comment: I think the fact that ants are able to carry objects that are 100 if not 1000 times their weights will play some role in answering this question. I think some more assumptions must be given to be able to really answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Energy won't kill anyone. I could absorb 1 ton of TNT (4.184 GJ) worth of energy unharmed *given enough time*. The thing that hurts will be power or force. But [experiencing massive g's won't harm you for short enough periods of time](http://gizmodo.com/why-the-human-body-cant-handle-heavy-acceleration-1640491171), so let's look at power. Assume both a human and ant have the same velocity immediately before impact. Then there is a linear relationship between ant energy to human energy, their mass ratio is the factor.

$$
\frac{E_a}{E_h} = \frac{m_a~v^2}{m_h~v^2} = \frac{m_a}{m_h}
$$

However, the problem comes in when the ant needs to stop vs the human needing to stop. If we assume the ant and human have similar enough geometry and density (they really don't but just so we don't base this off specific ant and person sizes) then their mass ratio is their volume ratio which is the cube of their length scaling ratio, seen below,
$$
\frac{m_a}{m_h} = \frac{\rho V_a}{\rho V_h} = \frac{{l_a}^3}{{l_h}^3} = \bigg(\frac{l_a}{l_h}\bigg)^3
$$

If you need to get rid of all that kinetic energy on impact, then you'll need to displace it in some length I've called $l$, but let's call the mass ratio $\mu=m_a/m_h$ and the length ratio will be $\mu^{1/3}$

If we want to displace $v$ in $l$ let's say at constant acceleration because this is the smallest maximum acceleration the body would experience for a drop, I understand this violates what I referenced, but let's assume $l$,$v$, and $a$ are such that the time is large enough to be dangerous for these accelerations.

$$
v^2 = 2al \\
a = \frac{v^2}{2l}
$$

Then we'll want the time from quadratic equation and we can compute average power
$$
-l = -vt+at^2 = vt + \frac{v^2}{2l}t^2, ~ t>0 \\
t = \frac{v \pm \sqrt{\strut v^2+4lv^2/2l}}{v^2/2l} \\
t = \frac{v \pm \sqrt{\strut 3v^2}}{v^2/2l} = \frac{2l}{v}(1 \pm \sqrt{3})\\
t = \frac{2l}{v}(1 + \sqrt{3})
$$

The power for the impact is the the energy dispersed over the time of impact: $P=E/t$
$$
P = \frac{mv^2}{2l(1+\sqrt{3})/v} = \frac{mv^3}{2l(1+\sqrt{3})}
$$
Comparing the ant to the human
$$
P_a = \frac{m_av^3}{2l_a(1+\sqrt{3})} \\
P_h = \frac{m_hv^3}{2l_h(1+\sqrt{3})} \\
\frac{P_a}{P_h} = \frac{m_a}{m_h}\frac{l_h}{l_a} = \mu~\mu^{-1/3} \\
\frac{P_a}{P_h} = \mu^{2/3}
$$

This just tells us that an ant uses less power to stop the fall, but if we compare to their individual masses, and call this the effective damage $D$

$$
\frac{P_a}{m_a} = D_a \\
\frac{P_h}{m_h} = D_h \\
\frac{D_a}{D_h} = \frac{P_a}{P_h}\frac{m_h}{m_a} = \mu^{2/3} \mu^{-1} = \mu^{-1/3} \\
D_a = D_h \mu^{-1/3}
$$

Assuming $m_a=10g$ and $m_h=70kg$, $\mu=143\cdot10^{-6}$ so $D_a/D_h \approx 19$. Telling us that an ant would have about 20 times the hurt. Using values found in Farcher's article, $m_a=0.3g$ and $m_h=82kg$, then $D_a/D_h \approx 65$.

But this is assuming that the time of impact will be large enough to be important, but this time is proportional to the length the body will use to land and inverse to the speed of impact, so if the ant travels quickly enough relative to this length, it will be too short of a time to be damaged. Since we're assuming both the ant and the human have the same speed, the human is less likely to fall into the short time range of impact durations.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm just missing some points: what kills you is power; however, in the end, you say that you need enough time for that power to kill you. But power*time= energy so isn't that the same as saying that enough energy kills you? I'm explaining this myself by saying that you need a minimum energy (which you won't reach if the time is too little, even if power is great) to kill you but only if that energy is delivered fast enough (high power) to you. 
Another point: why do you define damage to be power over mass? Would a bigger mass "respond" better to the same power?

Comment: Yes! That's exactly it, one must exceed a minimum energy and beyond that, as the power gets larger, one is more injured. I was considering this contradiction myself. I knew I could eat millions of joules in a meal, but that also a fall of 20m, corresponding to near 15 kJ would kill me, assuming continuity, then there would be a region of large enough times and large enough power. About choosing power/mass it's not a very good metric, but the idea was - assuming energy distributed uniformly in the body - then a larger/more massive body would have each particle within them absorbing less energy.

Comment: If you wanted to be really thorough you could analyze how stress propagates through each geometry, which is difficult. Maybe to reduce complexity you could consider that the impact is on something not deformable the way an appendage is. As in, consider a blow to the chest or head since you won't have to model how the leg muscles absorb part of the impact. But that's really thorough, what I did had some not so viable assumptions, but I'd imagine the trend is similar. If you're not familiar, stress is amount of energy stored per volume in a real body from a force causing it to deform.